# Random Generator with Picture Box set to visible

Tags: c#

my question is as follows i have 6 picture boxes, when the program runs they are set to invisible, i also have a button , when this button is pressed each time one of the pictureboxes must be set to visible. Please hea

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, is this ASP.NET, winforms, WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: yes it is winforms i havent tried anything , i need to know how to use the random generator and everytime i press the button one of the 6 picture boxes which was initially set to invisible should be set to visible after i press the button

Comment: Have you taken a look at the help section for the random generator?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please read about Random in C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sr/Vsexpressvcs/thread/55fb3116-c978-4ac8-9381-a2605e16e256

After you'll understand how does random works you'll have no problem solving your issue.

Basically its gonna be like this:

1.button pressed event

2.generate random number

3.use the random number to determine which picture box will appear

Remember to check what will happen if the Picture box is already visible.
Also, you haven't mentioned if you want to choose from the Picture Boxes left invisible or just randomly select one of the six Picture boxes

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer , one final think after i generate a random number how would i link this random number to the picture box, i want to select one of the six picture boxes which are all invisible and each time one must be turned to visible

Comment: It would be best if you think that yourself.
But for example, you can keep you picture box in an array and then address random picture box with random number used as array index, or just make switch statement.